# 'No Space Left on Device' error when Pipenv tries to lock file

Tags: python, sphero

I am new to Pipenv, having only installed it to run Sphero's SDK, and while trying to install additional modules, I came across this problem.  Pipenv would install the packages just fine, but then it would say that my Pipfile.lock was out of date.  It automatically started installing the newer file, then I get this: `Locking [dev-packages] dependencies... Locking [packages] dependencies... ✘ Locking Failed!`  
It then gives me a long list of errors larger than my display, but at the end it says this: `OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device`. What is wrong with my device?

Comment: your HDD is full

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+space+left+on+device -- doesn't any of these answer your question?

Comment: It said the same thing even after transferring it from a 32 GB card to a 64 GB card.  Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

So...I forgot a key piece of information.  I originally ran this on a 32GB card, but when I got this error for the first time I ordered a 64GB card to fix it.  This didn't help, and that's when I put the problem up here.  After digging around the web, I discovered that I need to re-configure my Raspberry Pi to use all 64GB of the card with `sudo raspi-config`.  After this, the package was able to install successfully.